# How to implement asynchronous queue?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Given following variation of queue:

```
interface AsyncQueue<T> {
    //add new element to the queue
    void add(T elem); 
    //request single element from the queue via callback
    //callback will be called once for single polled element when it is available
    //so, to request multiple elements, poll() must be called multiple times with (possibly) different callbacks
    void poll(Consumer<T> callback);
}
```

I found out i do not know how to implement it using java.util.concurrent primitives! So questions are:

- What is the right way to implement it using java.util.concurrent package?
- Is it possible to do this w/o using additional thread pool?

Comment: Sorry guys, with all that Scala i've forgot how java futures work). Will edit the question soon

Comment: Future is just an interface with a couple of simple methods.

Comment: @aioobe you may find this interesting: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: Right. I've used Scala a fair bit myself, and I'm familiar with futures. Your question was tagged with Java however.

Comment: @aioobe yes, because problem is language agnostic and scala runtime is still too poor. So, i want Java solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AsyncQueue` is very similar to a `BlockingQueue` such as `ArrayBlockingQueue`. The `Future` returned would simply delegate to the `ArrayBlockingQueue` methods. `Future.get` would call `blockingQueue.poll` for instance.

---

As for your update, I'm assuming the thread that calls `add` should invoke the callback if there's one waiting? If so it's a simple task of creating one queue for elements, and one queue for callbacks.

- Upon add, check if there's a callback waiting, then call it, otherwise put the element on the element queue
- Upon poll, check if there's an element waiting, then call the callback with that element, otherwise put the callback on the callback queue

Code outline:

```
class AsyncQueue<E> {

    Queue<Consumer<E>> callbackQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<E> elementQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public synchronized void add(E e) {
        if (callbackQueue.size() > 0)
            callbackQueue.remove().accept(e);
        else
            elementQueue.offer(e);
    }

    public synchronized void poll(Consumer<E> c) {
        if (elementQueue.size() > 0)
            c.accept(elementQueue.remove());
        else
            callbackQueue.offer(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also this class doesn't use a thread pool, not would the OP need to.

Comment: My first implementation used the same idea) Drawback is that both methods must be synchronized... Is there better solution i wonder?

Comment: Both are synchronized, but none of them are blocking, so I don't think it's a big issue. You could of course use blocking queues as backing queues, but it would get hairy quickly I believe.